# How can I persist my components when navigating through my app?

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

My homepage takes a second to load some images I'm pulling from an API. When I navigate away from my homepage and then back to it again the images take a second to load again.

How can I persist components I navigate away from so that they only have to load once?

Comment: I don't mind a little loading, but in case of an API it can be problematic. Take a look at [prefetching](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#prefetch) for the react-native image component, maybe it can help?

Answer (score 3):

React Native's built in `Image` component does not cache images, unfortunately.

Use Image component with built in caching mechanism. Here is [such component](https://github.com/wcandillon/react-native-img-cache)